# Output clean Data Frame Table with each Quarterly Price from a list of Stock

Tags: python, yfinance

Below is my code:

```
data = yf.download("FB GOOS WMT PFE PARA ORCL", start="2021-05-01", end="2022-05-30", group_by = 'column')
# Create output Dataframe for Excel 
output = {'Tickers': ['FB', 'GOOS', 'WMT', 'PFE', 'PARA', 'ORCL'], 
          '2021-09-30': data[ data.index == '2021.09.30']['Close'].transpose(),
          '2021.12.31': data[ data.index == '2021.12.31']['Close'].transpose(),
          '2022.03.31': data[ data.index == '2022.03.31']['Close'].transpose(),
          }

df = pd.DataFrame(output)
print(df)
```

I expected a clean table with 4 columns: Tickers, and then the following Dates from 2021-09-30 to 2022-03-31 with the prices in column form below. Instead I am getting errors stating that Data must be 1-dimensional. How do I fix this error to output the simple table?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are trying to get out of this, but check what you get when you execute ```data[ data.index == '2021.09.30']['Close'].transpose()```  The result is a data frame structure with two columns, which doesn't seem to be correct for the final results.

Comment: I need the associated closing price at each date so each of those lines corresponds to the date '2021.09.30' and the price with should be displayed on the left by the Ticker column. How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

After reading through your question a few times, I believe what you are trying to achieve is a DataFrame where the column headings are the Dates and the row indexes are the Ticker symbols.

The problem with your approach is that the call to `data[ data.index == '2021.09.30']['Close'].transpose()` produces a dataframe of two columns like:

```
Date    2021-09-30
FB  339.390015
GOOS    35.669998
ORCL    87.129997
PARA    39.509998
PFE 43.009998
WMT 139.380005
```

In reality you want the output to be a list of just the values.  To accomplish this update your output variable by

```
output = {'Tickers': ['FB', 'GOOS', 'WMT', 'PFE', 'PARA', 'ORCL'], 
          '2021-09-30': list(data[ data.index == '2021.09.30']['Close'].values[0]),
          '2021.12.31': list(data[ data.index == '2021.12.31']['Close'].values[0]),
          '2022.03.31': list(data[ data.index == '2022.03.31']['Close'].values[0]),
          }
```

When you perform `df = pd.DataFrame(output)` you will get:

```
Tickers 2021-09-30  2021.12.31  2022.03.31
0   FB  339.390015  336.350006  222.360001
1   GOOS    35.669998   37.060001   26.330000
2   WMT 87.129997   87.209999   82.730003
3   PFE 39.509998   30.180000   37.810001
4   PARA    43.009998   59.049999   51.770000
5   ORCL    139.380005  144.690002  148.919998
```

You can then set the index to Tickers by

```
df.set_index('Tickers', drop=True, inplace=True)
```

which then produces:

```
        2021-09-30  2021.12.31  2022.03.31
Tickers         
FB      339.390015  336.350006  222.360001
GOOS     35.669998  37.060001   26.330000
WMT      87.129997  87.209999   82.730003
PFE      39.509998  30.180000   37.810001
PARA     43.009998  59.049999   51.770000
ORCL    139.380005  144.690002  148.919998
```

Comment: That is great!!. am I able to delete the initial index column?

Comment: Yes, see updated solution.